# How to do Google Tag manager integration for UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I am trying to integrate Google tag manager with a simple UWP application,To achieve this I am using [SDKforGoogleAnalytics](https://github.com/dotnet/windows-sdk-for-google-analytics) library (This is the only library i can find in entire internet which does this job). Using this library I am able to send pageviews to Google and get back a success response. But in real google analytics dashbord this pageviews are never logged. an anyone point out what can be going wrong here? or is there any other way to integrate Google analytics with UWP?
My sample Request

```
  v:1
tid:UA-12345678-1
cid:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
an:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
av:1.0.0.0
cd:Main
sr:1366x768
vp:1366x696
ul:en-US
t:screenview
```

Response

```
    {
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-12345678-1\u0026cid=b91b73fb-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx\u0026an=2ec26bec-xxxx-xxxx-ab91-da6243a8c6aa\u0026av=1.0.0.0\u0026cd=Main\u0026sr=1366x768\u0026vp=1366x696\u0026ul=en-US\u0026t=screenview"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to track pageview instead sceenview. Mobile tracking with Universal Analytics has been deprecated so if you want to use measurement protocol use t=pageview and relative required parameters (like location).

Comment: Ok. that means the SDK I am using also must be depreciated. Is there any other SDK available that helps to integrate Google analytics on the UWP application?

Comment: Try searching Firebase SDK.

Comment: just to get Google analytics using firebase will be an overhead i believe

Comment: Great, let me know